# Allow user to add pin and store location using Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, marker

I'm using a jQuery plugin to embed a Google map onto a webpage. I'd like to allow the visitor to be able to add their own marker/pin on the map (the marker would identify the location of their home for sale), then save that location for later use (data sent via AJAX to server and stored in database).

Does anyone know how to create the personalised marker functionality please?

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a jquery wrapper around the google maps v3 API. Here is a demo page that does what you are workin on:

http://bobcravens.com/demos/GoogleMaps3/

There is a link to a blog post on that page with additional info. Hope that helps.

Bob